# SQL query for posts that are authored by multiple, but predetermined, accounts

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables; 'posts' and 'post_authors'. In post_authors multiple accounts can collaborate on a single post. I am having a little trouble thinking of a way to search for posts where multiple accounts, specified by a user input, collaborated.

As an example, I want to find all posts that both Jane Doe and John Doe have collaborated, even if there were additional collaborators in those posts.

My current query...

```
SELECT posts.ID
FROM posts
INNER JOIN post_authors author
    ON ( posts.ID = author.post_id AND author.user_id IN ( '144', '6' ) )
WHERE posts.status = 'publish'
```

This query retrieves all posts either of the accounts are attached to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach uses aggregation:

```
SELECT p.ID
FROM posts p
INNER JOIN post_authors pa
    ON p.ID = pa.post_id
WHERE pa.user_id IN ( '144', '6' ) AND
      p.status = 'publish'
GROUP BY p.ID
HAVING MIN(pa.user_id) <> MAX(pa.user_id);
```

This query works by restricting, for every post `ID`, to only records for users `144` and `6`.  It then asserts, via a `HAVING` clause, that both these users are present for each matching post `ID` group.

Note that I altered the table aliases to something shorter than the actual table names.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `group by` and `having`:

```
SELECT p.ID
FROM posts p INNER JOIN
     post_authors pa
     ON p.ID = pa.post_id 
WHERE pa.user_id IN ( '144', '6' ) and p.status = 'publish'
GROUP BY p.ID
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT pa.user_id) = 2;  -- number of items in list
```

The `post_id` is probably numeric.  If so, get rid of the single quotes.  Mixing data types can confuse the optimizer.

Note that I used table aliases that are abbreviations of the table names.  Shorter table aliases are easier to write and to read.